# Get parent data from a child

Tags: mobx-state-tree

What way is better? I think than first way is better. Import parent in child looks weird to me, but maybe I'm wrong.

RootStore:

```
export const RootStore = types
  .model('RootStore', {
    store1: types.optional(Store1, {}),
    store2: types.optional(Store2, {}),
    store3: types.optional(Store3, {}),
    store3: types.optional(Store4, {}),
    name: 'name'
  })

export const rootStore = RootStore.create()
```

First way:

```
export const Store1 = types
  .model('Store1', {
    some: ''
  })
  .views(self => ({
    get rootStore() {
      return getParent(self)
    },
    get name() {
      return self.rootStore.name
    }
  }))
```

Second way:

```
import { rootStore } from './rootStore'

export const Store1 = types
  .model('Store1', {
    some: ''
  })
  .views(self => ({
    get name() {
      return rootStore.name
    }
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers to this question are likely to be opinionated..

If you are going to do this, I think the first way is better. Just because it means the child does not need to know anything about it's parent other than that it exposes a `name` property.

That being said, I'm really not a big fan of either approaches.

Whether you use `getParent` or a closure, this encourages a coupling of the two models. This results in decreased modularity and harder testing since every `Store1` must be a child of a `RootStore` to function properly.

I think a better approach would be to remove the dependency between child->parent. However, if you are purposefully making use of the tree structure that MST provides, my suggestion might be better in theory than practice.

The simplest approach to removing the dependency is to have the caller of `Store1`'s actions/views pass whatever data is needed in as parameters. Once again, this does not always make sense in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is access the root node in the tree, then there's a dedicated helper function specifically for that case - [getRoot(self)](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/API/README.md#getroot).

> Given an object in a model tree, returns the root object of that tree.